# AngularJS with Webpack - minified assets causing issues with CSS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I recently moved Angular project to Webpack build system. After struggling with Angular Dependency Injection issues in JS source code, now that JS errors start occurring in CSS files. And I am totally confused why JS errors are targeting to a CSS file.

The error says;

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: eProvider <- e
```

And it occurs on every css file which is tarting with `/*!`. Also Same error start occurring on different css styles. e.g.

[image]

Can someone guide me how such JS injector errors occurring in CSS files?

My webpack config for CSS files are;

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      use: [
        { loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: false,
            sourceMap: true}
        }}
      ],
      fallback: 'style-loader'
    })
  },
```

I a requiring all css files together in entry file by;

```
function requireAll(requireContext) {
  return requireContext.keys().map(requireContext);
}

requireAll(require.context('./../assets/css/', true, /\.css$/));
```

Can someone guide what's wrong in above config.

**Update:**

I solved first error on comments of the files by adding `minimize: { discardComments: { removeAll: true }` into `css-loader` options. But second issue in styles still persist.

Comment: The error is definitely not coming from CSS. You are probably seeing it in CSS because something went wrong with the source map creation.

Comment: But if I remove that css line error do not appear in that css file again. That leads me to believe it’s really in css file.

Answer (score 3):

Finally found that if you minify AngularJS code with webpack you have incorporate a plugin to solve DI issues.

```
yarn add -D babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate
```

And then by adding it into babel plugins;

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|assets)/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader?name=js/[hash].[ext]',
      options: {
        presets: ['env'],
        plugins: ['transform-runtime', 'angularjs-annotate']
      }
    }
  }
```

That solves the issue.